# How to decorate one specific type with Autofac?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, decorator, autofac

Using the CQS pattern I have a query like this:

```
public class MyQuery : IQuery<View<SingleView>>
{
    public string Token { get; set; }

    public Criteria Criteria { get; set; }
}

public class MyQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<MyQuery, View<SingleView>>
{
    private readonly IProductRepository _productRepository;

    public MyQueryHandler(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        _productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    public View<SingleView> Handle(MyQuery query)
    {
        var data = // get my data

        return data;
    }
}
```

Off course I have many queries and their belonging QueryHandlers. Now I have a situation that I want to decorate only the `MyQueryHandler`. I don't want to decorate the rest of the queries.

I am using Autofac, but I just can't get it to work.

Here is how the queries are registered:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
    .As(type => type.GetInterfaces()
        .Where(interfaceType => interfaceType.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>)))
        .Select(interfaceType => new KeyedService("queryHandler", interfaceType)));

// Register query decorators
builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
    typeof(LogQueryDecorator<,>),
    typeof(IQueryHandler<,>),
    "queryHandler");
```

And here is the decorator I want to use for `MyQueryHandler`:

```
public class SaveMyQueryData : IQueryHandler<MyQuery, View<SingleView>>
{
    private readonly IQueryHandler<MyQuery, View<SingleView>> _queryHandler;
    private readonly IProductRepository _productRepository;

    public SaveMyQueryData(
        IQueryHandler<MyQuery, View<SingleView>> queryHandler,
        IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        _queryHandler = queryHandler;
        _productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    public View<SingleView> Handle(MyQuery query)
    {
        var result = _queryHandler.Handle(query);

        // do something with result

        return result;
    }
}
```

So how can I register `SaveMyQueryData` as a decorator just for `MyQueryHandler` using Autofac?

Answer (score 1):

I finally have it working the way I want. Here is my solution:

Make the decorator open instead of a closed type:

```
public class SaveMyQueryData : IQueryHandler<Q, R>
{
    private readonly IQueryHandler<Q, R> _queryHandler;
    private readonly IProductRepository _productRepository;

    public SaveMyQueryData(
        IQueryHandler<Q, R> queryHandler,
        IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        _queryHandler = queryHandler;
        _productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    public Q Handle(Q query)
    {
        var result = _queryHandler.Handle(query);
        var view = result as View<SingleView>; 

        // do something with view

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then when registering the type using Autofac, do this:

```
builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
  typeof(SaveMyQueryData<,>), 
  typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), 
  context => context.ImplementationType == typeof(MyQueryHandler));
```

The last line contains the magic. With the third parameter of `RegisterGenericDecorator` you can specify a condition when to apply the decorator. This is new since Autofac 4.9 and this solved my problem.